# How to define anchorborder for house-shaped PGF shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I am trying to define a shape for drawing agents in graphical illustrations of data provenance. These agents are usually drawn with a house-shaped symbol, i.e., with an irregular pentagon where the bottom two angles are right angles and the top left and top right angles are the same. See, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-prov-primer-20130430/#intuitive-overview-of-prov for an illustration. I have not embedded the image on that page as I am uncertain with regards to its licensing status.

Since no such shape exists by default in tikz, I am trying to define my own shape. I have managed to draw a background path that resembles my target shape, but I am unable to define the anchorborder so that tikz automatically points paths directed to nodes with that shape to the center of the shape.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,intersections}
\tikzstyle{agent}=[draw,agentshape]

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{agentshape}{
  \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{%
    \pgfpoint
      {\dimexpr.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
      {\dimexpr.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}%
  }
  \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}

  \savedanchor{\bottomleft}{%
    \pgfpoint{-\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{-\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{south west}{\bottomleft}

  \savedanchor{\bottom}{%
      \pgfpoint{.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{-\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{south}{\bottom}

  \savedanchor{\bottomright}{%
    \pgfpoint{\dimexpr\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{-\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{south east}{\bottomright}

  \savedanchor{\right}{%
      \pgfpoint{\dimexpr\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{\dimexpr.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}
  \anchor{east}{\right}

  \savedanchor{\topleft}{%
    \pgfpoint{-\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{\dimexpr\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{north west}{\topleft}

  \savedanchor{\left}{%
      \pgfpoint{-\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{\dimexpr.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}
  \anchor{west}{\left}

  \savedanchor{\topright}{%
    \pgfpoint{\dimexpr\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerxsep}{\dimexpr\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{north east}{\topright}

  \savedanchor{\top}{%
    \pgfpoint{.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{\dimexpr1.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox+\pgfshapeinnerysep}}
  \anchor{north}{\top}

  \anchorborder{%
    \@tempdima=\pgf@x%
    \@tempdimb=\pgf@y%
    %
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\topright}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@toprightangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\top}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@topangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\topleft}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@topleftangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\bottomleft}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@bottomleftangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\bottomright}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@bottomrightangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    %
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@givenangle}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{or(\@givenangle > \@bottomrightangle, \@givenangle <= \@toprightangle)}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
      \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\bottomright}{\topright}%
    \else%
      \pgfmathparse{and(\@givenangle > \@toprightangle, \@givenangle <= \@topangle)}%
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
        \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\topright}{\top}%
      \else%
        \pgfmathparse{and(\@givenangle > \@topangle, \@givenangle <= \@topleftangle)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
          \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\top}{\topleft}%
        \else%
          \pgfmathparse{and(\@givenangle > \@topleftangle, \@givenangle <= \@bottomleftangle)}%
          \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
            \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\topleft}{\bottomleft}%
          \else%
            \pgfmathparse{and(\@givenangle > \@bottomleftangle, \@givenangle <= \@bottomrightangle)}%
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
              \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}{\bottomleft}{\bottomright}%
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }

  \backgroundpath{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\bottomleft}
    \pgfpathlineto{\bottomright}
    \pgfpathlineto{\topright}
    \pgfpathlineto{\top}
    \pgfpathlineto{\topleft}
    \pgfpathclose
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[agent] (agent) at (1,1) {Foo};

  \foreach \coord in {-2,-1.5,...,2} {
    \path[draw,-] (-2,\coord) -- (agent);
    \path[draw,-] (2,\coord) -- (agent);
    \path[draw,-] (\coord,-2) -- (agent);
    \path[draw,-] (\coord,2) -- (agent);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following illustration:

[image: The result of compiling the above MWE]

As you can see, the paths coming in from the top and from the right-hand-side of the node appear to aim towards the lower left-hand side of the text box, while the paths coming in from the bottom and the left-hand-side of the illustration point toward the center of the lower part of the node. This is particularly noticable with the third path from the right in the top row and the third path from the top in the right-hand row.

How can I define the shape such that all incoming paths point towards the center of the node shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a `single arrow` shape can solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myhouse/.style={single arrow, 
        shape border rotate=90, 
        single arrow head extend=0pt, 
        single arrow tip angle=120}]

\node[myhouse, draw] (a) {House};

\node[myhouse, draw] at (30:2cm) (b) {House};

\draw (a)--(b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there had to be some easier way of drawing a house-shape. That helps me a lot for my present use case. I am still curious, however, why my original approach did not work, so I will wait for a while before I accept this answer :)